# Limit of $\frac{\sqrt{mx^2}}{\sqrt{\sin(m+1)x^2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I know it's an easy question, but I could use your help here, anyway.

Could you tell me how to prove that  $ \lim _{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\sqrt{mx^2}}{\sqrt{\sin(m+1)x^2}} = \sqrt{\frac{m}{m+1}}$? I know I should use the fact that $\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin \phi}{\phi}=1$. I've tried writing $\sin(mx^2 + x^2) = \sin(mx^2)\cos (x^2) + \cos(mx^2)\sin (x^2)$, but nothing comes to mind.

I would really appreciate your help. I know it should be obvious, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{mx^2}}{\sqrt{\sin(m+1)x^2}}\right)^2= \frac{mx^2}{\sin(m+1)x^2}\\=
\dfrac{mx^2}{\sin(mx^2)\cos (x^2) + \cos(mx^2)\sin (x^2)} \\
=\dfrac{1}{\frac{\sin(mx^2)\cos (x^2)}{mx^2}+\frac{\cos(mx^2)\sin (x^2)}{mx^2}}\underset{x\to{0}}\to\dfrac{1}{1+\frac{1}{m}}=\dfrac{m}{m+1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$ \lim _{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\sqrt{mx^2}}{\sqrt{\sin(m+1)x^2}}$$

$$=\sqrt m\sqrt{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{\sin(m+1)x^2}}$$

$$=\sqrt{\frac m{m+1}}\frac1{\sqrt{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(m+1)x^2}{(m+1)x^2}}}$$

as $x\to0,$ so will be $(m+1)x^2$ for finite $m$